# Extracting JSON response by Groovy Script (SoapUI)

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I have response like one below (it's just a fragment of whole response). How can I extract currencies codeName (RUB), name, symbol values? I'm using jsonSlurper and I was able to extract code only. I was trying to pass RUB (to make it dynamical) it didn't work. However if I typed manually RUB it gets proper value.

```
[{
   "name":    {
      "common": "Russia",
      "official": "Russian Federation",
      "nativeName": {"rus":       {
         "official": "Российская Федерация",
         "common": "Россия"
      }}
   },
   "tld":    [
      ".ru",
      ".su",
      ".рф"
   ],
   "cca2": "RU",
   "ccn3": "643",
   "cca3": "RUS",
   "cioc": "RUS",
   "independent": true,
   "status": "officially-assigned",
   "unMember": true,
   "currencies": {"RUB":    {
      "name": "Russian ruble",
      "symbol": "₽"
   }}
}]
```

What I have so far

```
import groovy.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

def responseContent = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("CountryCode").getPropertyValue("Response")
def slurperResponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseContent)

def String countryCurrency =slurperResponse.currencies[0]
def String countryCurrencyCode = countryCurrency.replace("{", "").substring(0,3)
def String countryCurrencyName = slurperResponse.currencies.**RUB**.name.[0] 
// in line above I'd like to pass the currency code dynamically)
```

Comment: `currencies['RUB'].name`

Comment: @daggett
so it should look like 
`def String countryCurrencyName = slurperResponse.currencies.['countryCurrencyCode'].name.[0]`
so the currencyCode can change dynamically (depends on country I get in request the currencyCode will be different, like RUB, PLN, EUR etc)? If yes, then it does not work :|

Comment: If you have a variable `cc = 'PLN'` then `currencies[cc].name` should work

Comment: @daggett thanks, I was adding "." before [cc], that's why it didn't work for me before